# Are there issues with Information Rights Management for Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint

What are your experiences with Information Rights Management for Sharepoint 2007?

Can it lock an Excel spreadsheet, so it can't be printed, distributed, or copied except by certain groups of users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bravax,

It should be able to, it works for doc, excel, pptp. You have to install the client on the sharepoint server, and server componente can be on a different server. There are some permissions issues on .aspx files oF the RMS server site that you may have change at the file level so that sharepoint allows you to use the security integrated with RMS.

With RMS you can control printing, if you have exchange, outlook allows you to control whom it is forwarded to and also you can timebomb emails to expire, with word and excel you should be able to control who modifies, reads, prints, and copy/paste. there are some other features, the new win2008 may have some newer things as well, it comes with win 2008 as a role/feature.

Regds

Eg